# android app one page to another page not working

Tags: android

Here I done code for 5 buttons like Aboutus,development,carriers,services,contactus.

Here I clicked about us button that shows errors as unfortunately app closed.

Here is my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button aboutus,development,service,carriers,contactus;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button aboutus=(Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
        aboutus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),aboutus.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aboutus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About us" 

           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/services"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Services"

           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/development"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Development" 
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/carriers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Carriers"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contactus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Us" 
           />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**aboutus.java**

```
public class aboutus extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
         }
}
```

**aboutus.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Aboutus Page"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** is this correct ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.globalinfosoft"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.globalinfosoft.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <Activity android:name= "aboutus"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),aboutus.class);
instead of above code use following code and instruction.
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,aboutus.class); 

and you have to declare the About us activity on AndroidManifest.xml

like this 

<Activity android:name= "aboutus"/>

Comment: Do you have a log from the crash?

Comment: i already done that one in code right

Comment: @user3152655, Hey have you seen my answer. You have not declared your aboutus activity in your manifest file.See my complete answer and do a copy paste from there.

Comment: @Manidroid, For declaring any new activity you must have use the package name or a dot before activity name. So put a dot like this:   <activity
            android:name=".aboutus"></activity>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.a;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button aboutus, development, service, carriers, contactus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button aboutus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
        aboutus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aboutus.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);

            }
        }); 

    }

    }
```

**Here is Androidmanifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.a.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.a.aboutus"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of v.getContext() use 'getApplicationContext()'.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aboutus.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Button aboutus=(Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
        aboutus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aboutus.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),aboutus.class);
startActivity(i);
```

instead of code use following code and instruction:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,aboutus.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

you have to declare the About us activity on AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
 <Activity android:name= ".aboutus"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure that you have declared the aboutus acitivity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
 <Activity android:name= "aboutus"/>
```

Second, you can use

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aboutus.class);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,aboutus.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),aboutus.class);
```